# Mac terminal failed to connect network

Tags: macos, proxy

I was using the network in out company. I must set a proxy to visit the outer internet. So, I set up the proxy configuration file with a proxy URL for Automatic Proxy Configuration in System Preferences.
[image]

While the problem comes, I can't use terminal to exec "git pull" or "wget". The error message seems like request timeout.

So, shall I set up a proxy for the terminal, and HOW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:** Export proxy

```
export https_proxy=proxy:port_no/
```

Example

```
export https_proxy=http://12.223.20.11:5187/
```

**Option 2**: Use -p option whenever you make request

```
git clone git_url -p proxy:port_no
```

Example

```
git clone my_git_url -p myproxy.com:9999
```